# Return to specific Watson Virtual Agent flow after a custom workspace

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-virtual-agent

I'm working with Watson Virtual Agent (WVA) and a custom conversation workspace (WCS) and was hoping that there was a way that I could go from a custom conversation flow back into a WVA flow.

My specific use case would be when I want to escalate to agent from within WCS. There are already preconfigured flows for this inside WVA which I think calling on would be the easiest way to complete the escalate to agent process.

I know that to force WCS to return to the WVA I need to somehow add

```
system.dialog_stack[0] == root
```

to the context, however, the instructions [here](https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/virtual-agent-dialog/blob/master/dialog-contract.md?cm_mc_uid=51487670932714780180393&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1478076271) don't go further than saying add to context. So far I just get errors when I add it to context with and without "" marks. Whilst I don't think that this would solve my issue I have actually been unable to test this.

I would welcome any answers specific to my example, specific to how to actually implement system.dialog_stack[0] == root in WCS or to the general question which I expect will have more uses for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Having done some more research I have discovered that it is possible to call on the specific Escalate to Agent flow type using an action.

The use of actions is explained in the documentation I linked to above although there is no list of preconfigured actions.

Here is an example of a node in WCS that would allow one to connect to agent using the connection that you've set up in WVA:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "I will connect you with an agent now.",
    "action": {
      "name": "agent"
    }
  }
}
```

Until there is a list of the actions available for use in WVA/WCS I don't know if this is a fix that would work with other flows. I found this using Postman extension in Chrome and using my WVA keys and replicated the action that was called during the Escalate to Agent flows in WVA.